How to program a nRF52811 chip?
Currently I work on an IoT project where I want to use nRF52811 chip for its BLE and low power consumption capabilities. I had tried to google and used AI to find out how to program such a chip after I get it. I saw that on Mouser or Digi-Key I get the chip itself, without any boards or ways to connect wires to it unless I solder them manually.
I saw that there is the nRF52840 DK (development kit) but it is quite expensive for me (I am looking for something in the range of 40-60$). I also saw that there is Segger J-Link EDU Mini available online but I am not sure how to connect the chip to it and start to program it.
I am a beginner in this field of IoT and so far I have never programmed an industrial chip. I am wondering what hardware components do I need and how to connect them in order to properly program and test out the chip. I barely found any tutorials on youtube and they were for different types of boards/chips than what I am looking for. I would be grateful if someone could tell me step by step how to proceed from getting the components up to program the nRF52811 chip or eventually show me a similar tutorial on youtube about how it's done.
After finishing the project I would like to post it online as a product, so I am wondering how could I go about mass programming the chips efficiently? A friend suggested that I could use a socket approach (like the processors on the PC have) in order to avoid soldering and be fast enough to go to the next one. How would I go about this as well? Would it be feasible or are there any better alternatives?
(P.S. I added the last question in the same post as they are somewhat related and perhaps people are knowledgeable enough to answer them both at once)

Well you need to put the SoC on a PCB with some components in order for it to work. See the reference designs in the product spec. For programming, this needs to be done over the SWDIO and SWCLK pins using the SWD protocol. Easiest is to use e.g. a SEGGER connected to these two pins. At the same time, the board must be powered.

I used Raspberry Pi for "Seeed XIAO nRF52840". It shouldn't be needed as you can double press reset button to switch into bootloader (but it didn't work for me somehow, so i ended with this: https://kiiv-cz.github.io/unbrick_xiao_ble/ )
